# Compute moments of maximum of multivariate normal distribution

Tags: normal-distribution, moments, order-statistics

I want to compute the first and second order moment of the maximum of a random vector from multivariate normal distribution, i.e., compute

$
E[\,\,Y\,],\,\,E[\,Y^2\,], 
$

where

$
Y=\max (X),\,\,\\
X=(x_1,x_2,...,x_k) \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\Sigma)\\
$

$\mu,\Sigma$ are mean vector (k$\times$1) and covariance matrix (k$\times$k), respectively.

The max operation means: $Y$ equals to the max element of vector $X$.

No independency of $x_1,x_2,...,x_k$ are imposed on $\Sigma$, i.e., $\Sigma$ is a general symmetric 
covariance matrix.

Any hints on how to solve this problem analytically? Approximate method will also be appreciated, e.g., Monte Carlo or Numerical integration, etc.

Comment: A Monte Carlo resolution is obvious. What is the question?

Comment: @Xi'an,  Hi,  Prof., yes, we can simply draw samples of X then compute empirical moments of Y. I tried this method, however it is slow due to the large sample size of X, so I want to seek some efficient methods (more efficient MC method or numerical integration method)

Comment: The distribution of the maximum may be a skew-normal, as discussed in that [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/145466/14893).

Comment: @Xi'an, thank u, I see that post, but is there a way to efficiently estimate the first and second moments of maximum of multivariate Gaussian?

Answer (score 5):

This paper by [Shi et al.](http://www.research.ibm.com/people/c/chandu/pubs/2013/todaes13.pdf) (2013) provides an algorithm for faster derivation of order statistics.

And [Arenallo-Valle and Genton (2008)](https://stsda.kaust.edu.sa/Documents/2008.AG.SPL.pdf) have this representation for the pdf of the Normal maximum, $X_{(N)}$:

[image: Statistics & Probability Letters, 78, p.30]

which involves $\phi_1$, the marginal pdf of $X_n$ and $\Phi_{n-1}$, the multivariate Normal cumulative distribution function of the (n-1) dimensional Normal. This cdf is available in the R package `mvtnorm`. The above expression simplifies when the components $X_i$ are exchangeable, i.e. when $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are invariant by permutation.

Comment: Hey, I had started writing the part about the Arenallo-Valle and Genton paper in my answer....

Comment: Would you by any chance know any resource that would demonstrate what happens to the distribution if we het $n \to \infty$? I assume it would converge to some extreme value distribution, but would be interesting to see the steps/proof.