# expectation involving the normal CDF

Tags: normal-distribution, expected-value, integral

I'm looking for a closed form expression for

$$\mathbb{E}\left[\Phi\left(aZ+b\right)^{k}\right] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi\left(az+b\right)^{k}\phi(z)\,dz$$

where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers, $k>0$ is an integer, $Z\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$, and $\phi(\cdot)$ and $\Phi(\cdot)$ are the density and distribution functions of a standard normal random variable. A special case has been treated [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/142931/how-can-i-compute-int-infty-infty-phi-leftazb-right2-phiz-dz?noredirect=1&lq=1) but I was wondering whether a general expression for all $k$ would be available.

Comment: Did you check some of the other similar posts?

Comment: Yes I did, but I haven't found an answer on this special case.

Comment: I searched a long time but the closest that I could find is the work of Marcello Hartmann, see here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.04736.pdf You probably can make it work... please post it if you do!