# How can I compute $\int F(x \mid a,b)f(x \mid w,z) {}dx$ in closed form?

Tags: normal-distribution, mathematical-statistics

Suppose $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of the normal distribution with mean $a$ and standard deviation $b$, and suppose $f$ is the probability density function of the normal distribution with mean $w$ and standard deviation $z$. How can I calculate this integral in closed form?

$$\int F(x \mid a,b)f(x \mid w,z) {}dx$$

It seems like my question is very similar to [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/how-can-i-calculate-int-infty-infty-phi-left-fracw-ab-right-phiw?lq=1), but crucially I'm not using that standard versions of the cdf or pdf. I tried converting my functions to their standard forms, but ended up with this:

$$\int \Phi\left(\frac{x-a}{b}\right)\frac{\phi\left(\frac{x-w}{z}\right)}{z} {}dx$$

And now I'm really confused!

P.S.: If the above does have a closed-form simplification, my true problem is actually closer to this:

$$\int F(2a - \xi - x \mid a,b)f(x \mid w,z) {}dx$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\int F(x \mid a,b)f(x \mid w,z) {}dx=E[F(Y \mid a,b)]=\Pr(X<Y)$$ 
where $Y \sim F(\cdot \mid w,z)$ is independent of $X \sim F(\cdot \mid a,b).$

Now, $X-Y \sim {\cal N}(a-w, z^2+b^2)$. The result is $\boxed{F(0 \mid a-w, \sqrt{z^2+b^2})}$.

Just to check:

```
> a <- 1; b <- 1
> w <- 2; z <- 2
> integrate(function(x) pnorm(x,a,b)*dnorm(x,w,z), lower=-Inf, upper=Inf)
0.6726396 with absolute error < 2.2e-09
> pnorm(0, a-w, sqrt(b^2+z^2))
[1] 0.6726396
```

Your last question directly follows from the first one by noting that
$$
F(2a - \xi - x \mid a,b) = 1 - F(x \mid 2a-\xi-a,b),
$$
therefore the result for your last integral is $\boxed{1-F(0 \mid a-\xi-w, \sqrt{z^2+b^2})}$.

```
> ksi <- 3
> integrate(function(x) pnorm(2*a-ksi-x,a,b)*dnorm(x,w,z), lower=-Inf, upper=Inf)
0.03681913 with absolute error < 0.00012
> 1- pnorm(0, a-ksi-w, sqrt(b^2+z^2))
[1] 0.03681914
```

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. Do you know how I would solve my P.S. problem similarly?

Comment: @user1637894 that's done now

Answer (score 1):

I'll gibe you the special case, which may point you to the general case, if it exists.

If the parameters of your distributions were the same, then we have

$$\int F(x|\mu,\sigma)f(x|\mu,\sigma)dx=\int F(x|\mu,\sigma)dF(x|\mu,\sigma)=F^2(x|\mu,\sigma)/2+Const$$

When parameters are not the same, then it gets hairy. There's got to be a way to convert them to standard normal, then it's be the same parameters (0,1). I think it'll give you solution with constants and scaling

So, for different parameters, something like this should be true:
$$F(x|\mu_2,\sigma_2)=   F(\frac{x-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\sigma+\mu|\mu,\sigma)$$

Then the integral becomes:
$$\int F(x|\mu_2,\sigma_2)f(x|\mu,\sigma)dx=\int F(\frac{x-\mu_2}{\sigma_2}\sigma+\mu|\mu,\sigma)dF(x|\mu,\sigma)$$

or

$$=\int y(a x +b) dy(x)=?$$
This got to have some beautiful solution, [Stiltjes integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/StieltjesIntegral.html) or something

UPDATE: I vaguely remember that this type of integrals was used a lot on game theory. The stochastic dominance of the second kind and stuff like that is all based on these integrals

Comment: Gaussians have nice Fourier transform properties, so thats somewhere to look.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Can you give any more details to go on re: the game theory stuff?

Comment: Look at this book,  there's pdf of the early version published by rand Corp somewhere in Internet http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/048664216X/ref=nosim/weisstein-20