# How can I calculate this integral? $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi (a + bX) \phi (c + eX) dx$

Tags: normal-distribution, probit, mathematical-statistics, integral

Suppose we have the density and distribution of the standard normal. How can one calculate the integral:

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \Phi (a + bX) \phi (c + eX) dx$

Note this is not included in the Wikipedia [list of integrals of Gaussian functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_Gaussian_functions).

Further, this is not the same as [How can I calculate $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\Phi\left(\frac{w-a}{b}\right)\phi(w)\,\mathrm dw$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/how-can-i-calculate-int-infty-infty-phi-left-fracw-ab-right-phiw) because that solution only works for a standard normal second term, i.e. $\phi (X)$ whereas this problem includes a coefficient and additional term. One cannot put into the same form as that case because $c$ and $e$ cannot be brought out of the normal density due to their involvement in the exponential component.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but we know that

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(a+bX) \phi( X ) dX=\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)$$

Comment: @ZERO Thanks, I am familiar with that integral and have seen short proofs on here, but unfortunately dealing with the second linear term is still unclear.

Comment: Are you sure it has an analytical closed form?

Comment: It was suggested to me that it does, but I am not sure.

Comment: I think that if the OP doesn't see how the other one answers this one (as was already established), then it's not really a dupe, since the question needs as an answer the explanation that connects one to the other.

Comment: @Glen_b In which case it really ought to be migrated to [math.se], because it's about changing variables in integration. :-)

Comment: @whuber I am in two minds about that; there's an extent to which the context means it's on topic (otherwise the original arguably should be migrated there as well; it's simply an integration problem). And on a similar basis ("it's really a mathematics question - it's just integration/differentiation/matrix algebra/change of variable...") a lot of the questions here would migrate. There's not a very clear dividing line about when it really counts as sufficiently statistical in context to count here. What I think just tips it over here is that the answer on which it relies is here.

Comment: Question: does this integral perchance calculate the probability that a random variable that obeys one Gaussian distribution takes on a value that is less than a second random variable that obeys another (different) Gaussian?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

But if you know the form discussed in comments

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\Phi(a+bx) \phi( x ) dx=\Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)$$

it's quite straightforward!

Just do the substitution $Z = c+eX$  (don't forget the Jacobian), and use the fact there that you already know (but in $z$ rather than $x$).