# variance and normal CDF

Tags: normal-distribution, variance, cumulative-distribution-function

If $X \sim N\left(\mu, \frac{\sigma^2}{n}\right)$, what can we say about the behaviour of 
$\text{Var}\{\Phi(X)\}$ with respect to $n$?

Is it true that this variance behaves as $O(n^{-1})$ for $n$ large enough?

I would show this using the Maclaurin series on $\Phi(x)$, assuming $x \ll 1$. Would this be correct? If so, could I restrict to the first terms of the series?

Thanks.

Comment: You could simply use the Delta method.

Comment: Sorry but if $\Phi(X)$ is the CDF, its distribution should be uniform(0,1) independently for $n$ and its variance should be $1/12$. Am I missing something?

Comment: I think this would be the case if $X$ was standard normal, which is not the case here.

Comment: An explicit formula for the variance in terms of  $\mu$ and $\sigma/\sqrt{n}$ is given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212421/variance-of-a-cumulative-distribution-function-of-normal-distribution/237374#237374.  Compute that through first order in $n^{-1}$.