# How can I calculate $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\Phi\left(\frac{w-a}{b}\right)\phi(w)\,\mathrm dw$ for the logistic distribution?

Tags: distributions, logistic, logistic-curve, logistic-distribution

Take the cumulative distribution function (cdf)

$\Phi(z) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-z)}$

and probability density function (pdf)

$\phi(z)=\Phi(z)(1-\Phi(z))$

of the logistic distribution.

How can one calculate the integral below?

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\Phi\left(\frac{w-a}{b}\right)\phi(w)\,\mathrm dw$$

Comment: Please specify what prompted this question. Is this homework?

Comment: It's actual research. I know it works for the Normal distribution but my problem is logistically distributed. I know that$$\int \mathrm{sigm}(x) \, N(x \mid \mu,\sigma^2) \, dx
\approx \int \Phi(\lambda x) \, N(x \mid \mu,\sigma^2) \, dx
= \Phi\left(\frac{\mu}{\sqrt{\lambda^{-2} + \sigma^2}}\right).$$ but would like to replace N by L.

Comment: You have flipped their names; what you have called the density is the distribution and vice versa.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Too long for a comment....

This question mixes up the words *density* and distribution: $\Phi(z) = \frac{1}{1+\exp(-z)}$ is the *distribution* function  of a logistic random variable, not the density as the OP calls it, while $\phi(z) = \Phi(z)(1-\Phi(z))$ is the corresponding *density* function even though the OP calls it the distribution function.  (OK, I see that the OP has corrected the nomenclature in the question, making the above not inapplicable any more).

Be that as it may, the result
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi\left(\frac{w-a}{b}\right)\phi(w)\,\mathrm dw = \Phi\left(\frac{-a}{\sqrt{b^2+1}}\right)$$
for **normal** random variables has been proved in two different ways in the answers to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/61080/6633). [My answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61098/6633) to this question explicitly uses the fact that the difference of two independent normal random variables is itself normally distributed. I suspect that a corresponding result *does not hold* for logistic random variables and so it might not be possible to adapt my method to solve the OP's problem. On the other hand, [the answer by whuber](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61098/6633) is based on solving partial differential equations, and might be more adaptable to what the OP is trying to do with logistic random variables.

Comment: Thanks for the shout-out: but unfortunately this integral doesn't appear to have any conventional closed form formula.  It *does* have such formulas for *rational* values of $a$ and $b$ (it's a matter of making an appropriate substitution in the integral, which reduces it to the integral of a rational function, which one can find through contour integration or otherwise), but the lengths of those formulas increase with the sizes of their numerators and denominators.