# Derivation of an Equation by Owen

Tags: normal-distribution, integral

How did Owen derive this relation?

Equation 10,010.3:

$$
\int G'(x)G(a+bx) dx = T\left(x,\frac{a}{x\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)+ T\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}},\frac{x\sqrt{1+b^2}}{a}\right)\\-T\left(x,\frac{a+bx}{x}\right)-T\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}},\frac{ab+x(1+b^2)}{a}\right)+G(x)G\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1+b^2}}\right)
$$

in terms of normal CDF $G(x)$, the normal pdf $G'(x)$ and Owen's $T$-function. I cannot find the derivation nor the derivative of the $T$-function, only its definition both in Owen's Table of Normal Integrals and on Wikipedia, thus bluntly taking the derivative does not work.

Comment: For the definite integral see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61080/how-can-i-calculate-int-infty-infty-phi-left-fracw-ab-right-phiw.  Note that the integral on the left hand side of the equation is implicitly over some interval determined by "$x,$" presumably $(-\infty,x].$  Once you interpret this integral in an ordinary regression context, the definition of $T$ on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Owen%27s_T_function) makes short work of this formula.

Comment: It is very interesting to me that this question is unanswered. Of course @whuber is correct with their statements but in my opinion, the question is not answered by a long shot.