Distribution of medians of triplicate samples taken from Gaussian distribution
My Monte Carlo simulation seems to show that the standard deviation of the medians of triplicate samples taken from the Gaussian distribution approaches 2/3 of the SD of the original distribution.  Intuitively this appears to be a similar sampling strategy as taking the average of the triplicate sample (rather than the median) - the idea behind the standard error of the average.  While the reduction of the estimation of the population SD is lower with the median vs. the average (1/sqrt(3)), it seems to have the practical advantage of censoring the outliers if the samples are contaminated.
Unlike the CLT for the standard error, I can't find any theory supporting the value of 2/3*SD when using the median of the triplicate method - it's all based on simulation.  Could anybody point me in the right direction?
p.s. I sampled in triplicates from other distributions.  The SD of the distribution of medians taken from each triplicate is for Lognormal: 0.501, for Uniform: 0.775, and for Triangular: 0.702.  In my application (a series of Systolic and Diastolic blood pressure measurements) this sampling works almost like a smoothing median filter of a time series. It seems to be quite practical in monitoring hypertension.  I still don't understand the theory behind it - is it possible to calculate the expected scatter reduction when taking the median of a triplicate sample in a similar closed-form fashion as it is done for the Standard Error of the Mean (e.g. of a triplicate sample)?

Maybe Standard error of the median or Central limit theorem for sample medians or How to obtain a confidence interval for a percentile?.

I suspect $0.669829 , \sigma$ is closer than $\frac23 \sigma$.  Try sd(qnorm(qbeta(ppoints(10^6),2,2))) using R

Could you explain the Beta dist. in there? @Henry

It's the distribution of the middle of three observations from a Uniform distribution, i.e., the distribution of the percentile that the median of three will be at.

@MaciejTomczak as jbowman says.  More generally the $k$th order statistic from a sample size $n$ from $[0,1]$ has a Beta$(k,n-k+1)$ distribution.

For the uniform distribution I get $\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}} \approx 0.7746$ as the ratio.  But I think for the lognormal the ratio depends on $\sigma$ (if one characterizes the lognormal in the usual way with parameters $\mu$ and $\sigma$).

The value for the triangular distribution ($\frac{\sqrt{\frac{69}{35}}}{2}$) matches your simulations.

@JimB For uniform simulation I got the same value - it was a typo in the original post.  Corrected.

@JimB could you briefly explain how you got those values and if there is a method that would work on other distributions without resorting to simulations?

I added in steps for uniform and triangular distributions.

This must be known somewhere because Mathematica (and likely MATLAB and Maple, too) solves this easily.
dist = OrderDistribution[{NormalDistribution[0, σ], 3}, 2]
Mean[dist]
(* 0 *)
pdf = PDF[dist, z] // FullSimplify

$$\frac{3 e^{-\frac{z^2}{2 \sigma ^2}} \left(1-\text{erf}\left(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2} \sigma }\right)^2\right)}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi } \sigma }$$
Now the variance:
var = Integrate[z^2  pdf, {z, -∞, ∞}, Assumptions -> σ > 0]

$$\frac{\left(\pi -\sqrt{3}\right) \sigma ^2}{\pi }$$
So the standard deviation is
FullSimplify[var // Sqrt, Assumptions -> σ > 0]

$$\sqrt{1-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi }} \sigma$$
or approximately $0.6698291607 \sigma$.
Triangular distribution
The pdf of a triangular distribution is given by
$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
 \begin{array}{cc}
  4 z & 0\leq z\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
  4 (1-z) & \frac{1}{2}<z\leq 1 \\
 \end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$
The mean is 1/2 and the variance is
$$\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 4 \left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 (1-z) \, dz+\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} 4 \left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 z \, dz=1/24$$
The pdf for the median of 3 observations from that triangular distribution is
$$\begin{array}{cc}
 \{ & 
 \begin{array}{cc}
  48 \left(1-2 (1-z)^2\right) (1-z)^3 & \frac{1}{2}<z\leq 1 \\
  48 z^3 \left(1-2 z^2\right) & 0\leq z\leq \frac{1}{2} \\
 \end{array}
 \\
\end{array}$$
The mean is again 1/2 and the variance is
$$\int_0^{\frac{1}{2}} 48 \left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 z^3 \left(1-2 z^2\right) \, dz+\int_{\frac{1}{2}}^1 48 \left(z-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 \left(1-2 (1-z)^2\right) (1-z)^3 \, dz=\frac{23}{1120}$$
The ratio of the standard deviations is
$$\frac{\sqrt{23/1120}}{\sqrt{1/24}}=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{69}{35}}}{2}\approx 0.702038$$
Uniform distribution
As noted by @Henry the pdf for the median from a sample size of 3 from a uniform distribution on [0, 1] is a Beta(2,2).  The associated pdf is
$$6(1-z)z$$
So the mean is 1/2 and the variance is
$$\int_0^1 (z-1/2)^2 * 6 (1-z)z\, dz=1/20$$
The variance of a uniform distribution is 1/12.  So the ratio of the standard deviations is
$$\frac{\sqrt{1/20}}{\sqrt{1/12}}=\sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}\approx 0.774597$$

+1 confirming my earlier calculation with sd(qnorm(qbeta(ppoints(10^6),2,2))) using R

Yes, the calculation is straightforward: just use the density of the median to compute the mgf.  The density is proportional to $\Phi(z)(1-\Phi(z))\phi(z).$

Is there a general principle behind it - i.e. how does it work for the median of triplicates taken from distributions that are not Gaussian (or triangular or uniform)?

@MaciejTomczak https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_statistic#Probability_distributions_of_order_statistics

@Glen_b Thanks for spotting that.  I've now included the missing square root signs.

Suppose $X_1, X_2, X_3 \text{ i.i.d. } \sim N(0, 1)$, then the density of the median $M := X_{(2)}$ is given by:
\begin{align*}
f_M(x) = 6\Phi(x)(1 - \Phi(x))\phi(x), \; x \in \mathbb{R}, \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{align*}
where $\phi$ and $\Phi$ are pdf and cdf of standard normal distribution respectively.
Since $f_M$ is symmetric about $0$, clearly $E(M) = 0$, and
\begin{align*}
E(M^2) = 6\int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\Phi(x)(1 - \Phi(x))\phi(x)dx. \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align*}
To evaluate the integral in $\eqref{2}$, we need the following two results: for $b > 0$,
\begin{align*}
& \int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi(b^{-1}x)\phi(x)dx = \frac{1}{2}, \tag{3}\label{3} \\
& \int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi^2(b^{-1}x)\phi(x)dx = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{\pi}\arctan\left(\frac{b}{\sqrt{2 + b^2}}\right).  \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{align*}
See technical notes at the end of the answer for discussions on identities $\eqref{3}$ and $\eqref{4}$.
Now for $|t| < 1/2$, define
\begin{align*}
I(t) &= \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{tx^2}\Phi(x)(1 - \Phi(x))\phi(x)dx \\
&= \int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(x)(1 - \Phi(x))\phi(\sqrt{1 - 2t}x)dx \\
&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{1 - 2t}}\left[\int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - 2t}}\right)\phi(x)dx - \int_{-\infty}^\infty\Phi^2\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1 - 2t}}\right)\phi(x)dx\right].
\end{align*}
By $\eqref{3}$ and $\eqref{4}$, this is
\begin{align*}
I(t) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1 - 2t}}\arctan\sqrt{\frac{1 - 2t}{3 - 2t}}.
\end{align*}
Therefore,
\begin{align*}
I'(0) = \frac{1}{6} - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6\pi}. 
\end{align*}
Since $I'(0) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2\Phi(x)(1 - \Phi(x))\phi(x)dx = 
\frac{1}{6}E(M^2)$, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\operatorname{Var}(M) = E(M^2) = 1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi},
\end{align*}
i.e, $\operatorname{sd}(M) = \sqrt{1 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\pi}}$, agrees with @JimB's Mathematica answer.

Technical Notes
$\eqref{3}$ and $\eqref{4}$ are examples of Integrals of Gaussian Functions.  For a comprehensive list of this type of integrals, this Wikipedia's link is helpful.
The better-known identity $\eqref{3}$ has been proven in this Cross Validated link.
$\eqref{4}$ is considerably more difficult to prove (whereas it indeed holds according to the Wikipedia's link I shared above) than $\eqref{3}$. I have posted a question on Mathematics StackExchange and added my own proof therein. The key of the proof is, as one may have guessed, applying Feynman's integration trick based on the identity $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \Phi(a + bx)\phi(x)dx = \Phi\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{1 + b^2}}\right)$.

Re "not easy:" that's why in a comment I suggested computing the mgf.  That reduces to two integrals like the one discussed at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/61080.
